# Which is the better service to monitor(count) invocation of API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an API , I have created an usage plan of 20 request/day and associated an API key to that api. Now I want to monitor invocation of that API and create an alarm when the API invoked for 15 times. Is cloudwatch suitable for this task? How could I create alarm in cloudwatch for above purpose?

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch supports publishing custom metrics from the applications.

"Put Metric Data" API of cloudwatch can be used to publish to cloudwatch.

Custom Metrics Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html

Once the metrics are published, you can set alarms using CloudWatch alarms for various thresholds.

Alarms Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

Comment: I am facing problem in Evaluation Period and Datapoints to Alarm. What values should I enter for above scenario?

Comment: Data points are defined by the period set for a metric. For a “1 minute” period, there is one data point every minute, similarly for a "5 min period", there is one data point every 5 minutes...
Evaluation Period is the number of the most recent data points to evaluate when determining alarm state. If you set to say 3, the alarm will trigger only after 3 times the threshold gets breached. It depends on your requirment.